# Pass number into event

Tags: c#, event-handling, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I would like to ask you for help.
I dynamically creating a lot of textboxes and I am using LostFocus event (C#).

Is it possible to create event with passing of number ID of textbox?

Something like

```
(object sender,EventArgs,int ID)
```

and

```
tbx.LostFocus+= EventHandler(MySubFunction(3)?? --3 is my ID of textbox
```

Thank you for help, I am lost in this
I do not know how to add any number to `EventHandler` call

Comment: You should include some code snippets of what you have tried doing. It is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: use the `Tag` property of your `TextBoxes` eg. on creating `textBox.Tag = "Hello World";` on the event side `(sender as TextBox).Tag`

Comment: @RandRandom Minor complaint, but it the object isn't a TextBox, that code will throw a null ref exception :)

Comment: @DavidG - indeed it will, but we want to keep stackoverflow alive, so that would be a question for another day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using winforms you can use the `Tag` property to distinguish between different controls:

```
var textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.Tag = 42;
textbox.LostFocus += TextboxLostFocus;

...
void TextboxLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(sender is TextBox txtBox && txtBox.Tag is int textboxNum){
      // use textboxNum
   }
}
```

Or you can use lambdas to register your event with a built in number:

```
var textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.LostFocus += (o, e) => TextboxLostFocus(42);

...
void TextboxLostFocus(int textboxNum){
      // use textboxNum
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is much more easy way than I tried to create.